# Node.js + Socket.io: Client not receiving message

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am building a very basic chat system between two clients. While the server can receive a message from the client, it cannot send the message to the client (the `receiveMessage` event is not triggered when the server sends the message to the client). Below is my code client-side:

```
$("#send-msg").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    socket.emit("sendMsg", [$("#msg-text").val(), chattingWith]);
});

socket.on("receiveMessage", receiveMsg);

function receiveMsg(data) {
    console.log("received msg"); // NOT OUTPUTTED
}
```

Below is my code server-side:

```
var socket = io.connect();
var io = socket(server, { pingTimeout: 63000 }); 
io.sockets.on("connection", userConnect); 

function userConnect(user) {
    user.on("sendMsg", sendMsg);

    function sendMsg(msgData) {
        var msgContent = msgData[0];
        var receiverId = msgData[1];
        console.log("received message from " + receiverId); // ACTIVATED
        io.to(receiverId).emit("receiveMessage", [msgContent, receiverId]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `receiverId`?  Where does it come from? Why do you think `io.to(receiverId)` will reach the correct socket?  If you want to send back to the sender, you would do `user.emit(...)`, since in your structure `user` is the socket that send this message.

Comment: try using
user.emit("receiveMessage", [msgContent, receiverId]);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change a little your code:
Client side (I assume that `chattingWith` is a unique room or chat id):

```
$("#send-msg").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   socket.emit("send message", $("#msg-text").val(), chattingWith);
});

socket.on("send Message", receiveMsg);

function receiveMsg(data) {
  console.log(data); //An array should be an output
}
```

Server side code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
 socket.on('send message', function(data, id){
        socket.join(id)
        io.sockets.in(id).emit('sendMessage', {
            data: data,
        })
    })
})
```